# Intellij Idea. Add parameter to launch URL?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, intellij-idea, actionscript

I have pure ActionScript project, that produces SWF file. The problem is that after 3-4 compilations SWF is cached somehow :) And my changes doesn`t work.

Cache doesn`t work if I add some dummy parameter to URL like this:
[image: Config]

But after 3-4 compilations I should change it again. Is some there some tool to generate and add random parameter ?

Answer (score 1):

You may save the swf path in a xml file, it would be like this

```
<swf name="a.swf">
    <path>somefolder/a.swf?time=1234567</path>
</swf>

<swf name="b.swf">
    <path>somefolder/b.swf?time=7654321</path>
</swf>
```

And then you can use Date class to get the current time and set it as parameter. It's easy to change the xml and load it.

```
 var d:Date = new Date();

 //replace the path with new value
 var newPath:String = "someFolder/a.swf?" + String(d.time);
```